# MySQL not creating FK

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm having trouble with forwarding database to server. Here's log:

> Executing SQL script in server
>
> ERROR: Error 3780: Referencing column 'id_users' and referenced column 'id_users' in foreign key constraint 'fk_watch_later_users1' are incompatible.

SQL Code:

Table `mydb`.`watch_later`

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`watch_later` (
          `id_wl` INT NOT NULL,
          `id_users` INT NULL,
          `id_films` INT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id_wl`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `id_wl_UNIQUE` (`id_wl` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `fk_watch_later_films1_idx` (`id_films` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `fk_watch_later_users1_idx` (`id_users` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_watch_later_films1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`id_films`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`films` (`id_films`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_watch_later_users1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`id_users`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`users` (`id_users`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 15 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Table `mydb`.`users`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` ( 
  `id_users` INT NOT NULL,
  `users_nickname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `users_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `users_surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `users_birth` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_users`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_users_UNIQUE` (`id_users` ASC) VISIBLE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Tell me please how can I fix it? MySQL version is 8.0.18

Comment: What part of the message do you not understand?  It seems pretty clear to me.  The types are not the same.

Comment: Types are both INT

Comment: Then please also post the `users`-table.

Comment: ```-- Table `mydb`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
  `id_users` INT NOT NULL,
  `users_nickname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `users_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `users_surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `users_birth` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_users`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_users_UNIQUE` (`id_users` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;```

Comment: This works fine here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84134dfedfa1a05f82bbeda25eff961d

Comment: You are doing something you are not telling us. It works well in SQL fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4120fa

Comment: Well, I'm not doing anything else. I builded schema in Workbench and need to forward it to server. But when I choose "Forward Engineer" - here comes this error